# Libgdx game wont run from Google Play Store

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, libgdx, apk

I've uploaded an app using Libgdx to the Play Store.  However, when I downloaded it on another phone, it wouldn't run.  I used the setup of Libgdx games with multiple platforms (Android and Desktop) - where you have one Java project for the game code, then launch that game through a separate Android project.  For more info on this setup, I used this website:

http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/comment-page-2/

I feel like the Exported APK doesn't include the Java project (with all the game info on it).

**I can't post any pictures yet, so I can't show the project set up...but there's nothing extra really.  Assume you're starting from scratch on a project.

Any ideas?  Do I need to add a source folder under the Android project?  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried sideloading the exported APK to your device to test? attach the LogCat and see if any errors are being thrown

Comment: The APK build would not complete if it was missing the core (platform-independent) class files.  You'll need to get some debug logs.  See my comment on the suspiciously similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092753/publish-libgdx-game-to-google-play

Comment: Thank you both for getting back to me!  I did get some errors on the debug logs.  I've never used Logcat before though...so I'm not sure about what to do next.  Looks like the common error that came up said something along the lines of "Could not find class greenball.activity.GreenBall (my java project) referenced from method ball.activity.GreenBallActivity.OnCreate (my android project)".

That seemed to be the gist of the errors.  Any thoughts on next steps?  

And P.T. - yes very similar!  I didn't mean to overlook your post, just hadn't used Logcat yet and was seeing if anything else I knew

Comment: What's the whole error?  That exception is usually followed by another exception which says what caused the class not to be found.  (Search for "libgdx could not find class exception".)

Comment: You can post the link of images in the question (or comments) and other users (who are allowed to post images) can insert the images in your question. Good luck.

Comment: A couple of common issues that could cause this...(1) Make sure you've copied the native library folders (`armaebi-v7a`,`armaebi`,`x86`) into your `libs` directory in the Android project. Although you shouldn't need to do this if using the Gradle based setup. (2) Open the Android project properties, click Java Build Path in the sidebar, choose the Order and Export tab, and make sure everything is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have native libraries in the libs folder. Check your application.mk file to make sure you are compiling for all architectures. An Application compiled only for x86 will not work on an ARM device and an application compiled for ARM MIGHT not work on an x86 device. Also make sure you have the right permissions set on your manifest file to access features like camera,location etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input!  I looked into all of your suggestions, and it lead me to find something called "Grable".  I installed that and it looks like that software (which links with Eclipse) takes care of all the structuring of Libgdx games (libs, etc.).

However, I'm still getting an error when I try to debug the android app.  Here is the Debug stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2180    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Is anyone familiar with any additional steps for setting up a project using Grable?

Comment: There's a kind of error suggestion that comes up...it says "Source not found", then there's a button that lets you Edit Source Lookup Path

Comment: 06-09 22:10:32.317: E/Trace(1023): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)